# GORM: Preloading not working with nested associations?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to preload association ProfileData on Profile, where Profile is a collection type in ProfileCollection model. It loads the profiles / members of the collection, although not the inner associations of Profile such as ProfileData?

Code:

```
var collections []ProfileCollection
var error = database.
    Model(ProfileCollection{}).
    Preload(clause.Associations).
    Find(&collections).
    Error

if error != nil {
    log.Fatalln(error)
}

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(collections)
```

I've also tried loading them like so but nothing changed:

```
.Preload("Members.ProfileData")
```

JSON Output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test 1",
  "description": "Just one from the seeder.",
  "members": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "collection_id": 1,
      "path": "/",
      "created_at": "2021-09-05T01:40:06Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-05T01:40:06Z",
      "collection": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "members": null
      },
      "profile_data": {
        "id": 0,
        "profile_id": 0,
        "name": "",
        "username": "",
        "picture": "",
        "bio": "",
        "is_private": false,
        "other_data": null,
        "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "media_items": null,
      "origin": null,
    },
  ]
}
```

Structs:

```
type ProfileCollection struct {
    ID int64 `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Members []Profile `gorm:"foreignKey:collection_id" json:"members"`
}

type Profile struct {
    ID int64 `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    CollectionId int64 `json:"collection_id"`
    Path string `json:"path"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`

    ProfileData ProfileData `gorm:"foreignKey:profile_id" json:"profile_data"`
    MediaItems []ProfileMediaItem `gorm:"foreignKey:profile_id" json:"media_items"`
    Origin *Profile `gorm:"foreignKey:origin_id" json:"origin"`
}

type ProfileData struct {
    ID int64 `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    ProfileId int64 `json:"profile_id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Picture string `json:"picture"`
    Bio string `json:"bio"`
    IsPrivate bool `json:"is_private"`
    OtherData datatypes.JSON `json:"other_data"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

Comment: How about `Joins("Members").Joins("ProfileData")` instead of `Preload` ?

Comment: What error are you getting when preloading?